# Display complex Html text in android like gmail

Tags: android, html, webview, textview, xamarin.android

Hi i have to display html text with its style property, i tried both textview and webview .

when i use textview with Html.fromHtml("html text ") its showing only text without html style and other hand

when i use webview the whole content display in single line with horizontal scroll view

Using texview
[image]

using webview 
[image]

But its working well in gmaill android app

My code is for text view

```
var text = "<p style=\"margin: 0px 0px 1em; padding: 0px; border: 0px; font-size: 15px; clear: both; color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-family: \'Helvetica Neue\', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 19.5px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\">The main code is:</p><pre class=\"default prettyprint prettyprinted\" style=\"margin-top: 0px; padding: 5px; border: 0px; overflow: auto; width: auto; max-height: 600px; font-family: Consolas, Menlo, Monaco, \'Lucida Console\', \'Liberation Mono\', \'DejaVu Sans Mono\', \'Bitstream Vera Sans Mono\', \'Courier New\', monospace, sans-serif; color: rgb(57, 51, 24); word-wrap: normal; background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);\"><code style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; font-family: Consolas, Menlo, Monaco, \'Lucida Console\', \'Liberation Mono\', \'DejaVu Sans Mono\', \'Bitstream Vera Sans Mono\', \'Courier New\', monospace, sans-serif; white-space: inherit;\"><span class=\"com\" style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; color: rgb(128, 128, 128);\">// Use WideViewport and Zoom out if there is no viewport defined</span><span class=\"pln\" style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\">\nsettings</span><span class=\"pun\" style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\">.</span><span class=\"pln\" style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\">setUseWideViewPort</span><span class=\"pun\" style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\">(</span><span class=\"kwd\" style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 139);\">true</span><span class=\"pun\" style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\">);</span><span class=\"pln\" style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\">\nsettings</span><span class=\"pun\" style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\">.</span><span class=\"pln\" style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\">setLoadWithOverviewMode</span><span class=\"pun\" style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\">(</span><span class=\"kwd\" style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 139);\">true</span><span class=\"pun\" style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\">);</span><span class=\"pln\" style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\">\n\nsettings</span><span class=\"pun\" style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\">.</span><span class=\"pln\" style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\">setLayoutAlgorithm</span><span class=\"pun\" style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\">(</span><span class=\"typ\" style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; color: rgb(43, 145, 175);\">LayoutAlgorithm</span><span class=\"pun\" style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\">.</span><span class=\"pln\" style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\">TEXT_AUTOSIZING</span><span class=\"pun\" style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\">);</span></code></pre><p style=\"margin: 0px 0px 1em; padding: 0px; border: 0px; font-size: 15px; clear: both; color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-family: \'Helvetica Neue\', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 19.5px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\">The other option is to enable pinch zoom:</p><pre class=\"default prettyprint prettyprinted\" style=\"margin-top: 0px; padding: 5px; border: 0px; overflow: auto; width: auto; max-height: 600px; font-family: Consolas, Menlo, Monaco, \'Lucida Console\', \'Liberation Mono\', \'DejaVu Sans Mono\', \'Bitstream Vera Sans Mono\', \'Courier New\', monospace, sans-serif; color: rgb(57, 51, 24); word-wrap: normal; background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);\"><code style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; font-family: Consolas, Menlo, Monaco, \'Lucida Console\', \'Liberation Mono\', \'DejaVu Sans Mono\', \'Bitstream Vera Sans Mono\', \'Courier New\', monospace, sans-serif; white-space: inherit;\"><span class=\"com\" style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; color: rgb(128, 128, 128);\">// Enable pinch to zoom without the zoom buttons</span><span class=\"pln\" style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\">\nsettings</span><span class=\"pun\" style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\">.</span><span class=\"pln\" style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\">setBuiltInZoomControls</span><span class=\"pun\" style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\">(</span><span class=\"kwd\" style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 139);\">true</span><span class=\"pun\" style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\">);</span><span class=\"pln\" style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\">\n\n</span><span class=\"kwd\" style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 139);\">if</span><span class=\"pun\" style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\">(</span><span class=\"typ\" style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; color: rgb(43, 145, 175);\">Build</span><span class=\"pun\" style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\">.</span><span class=\"pln\" style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\">VERSION</span><span class=\"pun\" style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\">.</span><span class=\"pln\" style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\">SDK_INT </span><span class=\"pun\" style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\">&gt;</span><span class=\"pln\" style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\"> </span><span class=\"typ\" style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; color: rgb(43, 145, 175);\">Build</span><span class=\"pun\" style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\">.</span><span class=\"pln\" style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\">VERSION_CODES</span><span class=\"pun\" style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\">.</span><span class=\"pln\" style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\">HONEYCOMB</span><span class=\"pun\" style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\">)</span><span class=\"pln\" style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\"> </span><span class=\"pun\" style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\">{</span><span class=\"pln\" style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\">\n    </span><span class=\"com\" style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; color: rgb(128, 128, 128);\">// Hide the zoom controls for HONEYCOMB+</span><span class=\"pln\" style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\">\n    settings</span><span class=\"pun\" style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\">.</span><span class=\"pln\" style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\">setDisplayZoomControls</span><span class=\"pun\" style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\">(</span><span class=\"kwd\" style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 139);\">false</span><span class=\"pun\" style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\">);</span><span class=\"pln\" style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\">\n</span><span class=\"pun\" style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\">}</span></code></pre> "
```

set text for textview

```
var textView = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.mywebtext);
textView.TextFormatted = Html.FromHtml(text);
```

webview is

```
WebSettings settings = webView.Settings;
       //        webView.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#123456"));
        settings.UseWideViewPort = false;
        settings.LoadWithOverviewMode = false;
        settings.SetLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NarrowColumns);
        webView.LoadData(text, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WebView webview = (WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.webview);


String html = "<html><head><title>TITLE!!!</title></head>";
html += "<body><h1>text header</h1></body></html>";


webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(filePath, html, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

if there is no filePath:

```
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```